# Extract text after first upper case or space

Tags: r, dplyr, stringr

How can I extract all text after first space in a column where data is something like this

```
structure(list(value = c("1.1.a Blue sea", "1.2.a Red ball")), row.names = c(NA, -2L), class =c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

so I get a new column with just

```
Blue sea
Red ball
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the following code to select all text after the first white space:

```
sub("^\\S+\\s+", '', df$value)
```

Output:

```
[1] "Blue sea" "Red ball"
```

You can just use this to create it as a new column:

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
  mutate(new_value = sub("^\\S+\\s+", '', value))
```

Output:

```
# A tibble: 2 × 2
  value          new_value
  <chr>          <chr>    
1 1.1.a Blue sea Blue sea 
2 1.2.a Red ball Red ball
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `str_extract` from the package `stringr` to extract anything that starts with an upper case letter (`[[:upper:]]`) followed by one or more characters (`.+`) until the end of a string (`$`).

```
library(stringr)

str_extract(df$value, "[[:upper:]].+$")
```

If you don't want to use regex, you can use `str_split` to split strings into two parts by an empty space.

```
str_split(df$value, " ", n = 2, simplify = T)[,2]
```

#### Output

The above two methods have the same output:

```
[1] "Blue sea" "Red ball"
```